# Mondrian 4 documentation

Tags: olap, mondrian

I am about to start creating OLAP using Mondrian. Is there an official **Mondrian 4 documentation**? The documentation I found at [mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php) doesn't seem to cover the latest Mondrian version. I thought `virtual cubes` are replaced by `measure groups`. See an actual documentation stub below:

```
<Schema>
    <Cube>
        <Table>
        ...
        <Dimension>
        <DimensionUsage>
        <Measure>
        <MeasureExpression>
    ...
    <VirtualCube>
        <CubeUsages>
        <VirtualCubeDimension>
        <VirtualCubeMeasure>
```

Is there any other source or tutorial where can I start with Mondrian 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mondrian documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php) you mentioned is for older version - Mondrian 3.

There is a [**Mondrian 4 documentation**](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/head/documentation/schema.php#Schema_element).

Check the documentation stub:

```
<Schema>
    <PhysicalSchema>
        <Table>

    <Cube>
        <Dimensions>
        ...
        <MeasureGroups>
            <MeasureGroup>
                <Measures>
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/head/documentation/schema.php

This makes a back reference to Mondrian 3; so it must be more recent.